# Linear Transformations $ \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
        -4 & 3 & 2 \\
        -7 & 3 & -2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$.

Define the linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 $ as $T(x)=Ax $.

Find the images of $u = \begin{bmatrix} 
-5\\ -2 \\2 \end{bmatrix} $ and $v = \begin{bmatrix} 
a\\ b \\c \end{bmatrix}$ under $T$.

I'm really not sure what it's asking. I'm having trouble understanding how to set up linear transformations. Any hints on how I should start?

Comment: It is asking you to find $T(u)$ and $T(v)$.  This can be found by multiplying the matrices $Au$ and $Av$, justified by the definition of $T$.

Comment: Think of it in terms of elementary functions from algebra.  If I have a function f(x) = x$^2$ you could say of image of 2 under f is 4.  It works the same with matrices.  Thus T(u) is the image of the vector u under T which in this case is A since T(u) = Au.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x$ to be the vector $[x,y,z]^T$ and multiply it by your matrix $A$. That would be your linear transformation.

The 'image' of a vector under a function just means the value of the function when that vector is put in as an argument. So do $T(v)$ and $T(u)$ once you find out $T$ explicitly.

Comment: ohh, I see now. It makes sense. I'll give that a try. Notation sometimes confuses me.